# jqueryUI sortable flicker on Ctrl+F5 not on F5 (both) only on FF not on Chrome

Tags: jquery-ui, firefox, jquery-ui-sortable

I am facing flickering issue with the following setup when using JqueryUI sortable on connected lists. This only happens on reloading page using Ctrl+F5 on FireFox ver 31.0 and not when I reload using only F5. However it works well chrome ver 36.0.1985.125 m.
I have now jquery ver 1.10.2 and jQueryUI ver 1.10.3, I have tried using recent version of jQuery and jQueryUI but it did not help.

Any ideas how can I resolve flickering on Firefox.
Thanks.

Comment: What kind of flickering do you mean? It is a bit hard to help from the information you give. Can you make a jsfiddle that shows the problem? My best bet is that it is because you are redownloading all the files(ctrl+f5) and maybe the order you download the css and the javascript in causes the flickering.

Comment: @KristianBarrett its like the whole page is shaken. It happens first when I select a list item to move and then when i drop it to desired column.

Comment: @KristianBarrett here is the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/hiqarixi/11/edit?html,css). Its something like this what I have implemented. It works well here, but something goes wrong on my setup.
I must figure it out. Anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: You should look into when you load the different files and look into minifying your css and javascript. Try https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/ for Chrome. It can help give you some pointers on how to make your page load faster; which will probably help the flickering.